# How can I set ReSharper to ignore case-sensitivity when I search a file by name?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to turn off case-sensitivity in ReSharper when I search for a file by name -I mean by using the short-cut: "CTRL + SHIFT + T" ?

Comment: in my case navigation by Ctrl+Shift+T is not case sensitive by default..

Comment: But in my case, it is :( But at least it is a hope giving thing on such a possibility of settings change.

Comment: what version of Resharper are you using? In 5.1, the file search is case insensitive, you can use uppercase to match the camel case names.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are typing in the ctrl+shift+t window, and the file you are unexpectedly (not) seeing in the search results?

Answer (score 3):

If you only use lower-case it should work case-insensitive. But as soon as you write any upper-case the list switches to CamelCase search and you need to type in the right upper-case letters in the right order. You must not skip any upper-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about ReSharper, but if you are using Visual Studio 2010, you could use the build in navigate to functionality (default key binding is ctrl + ,). This search is case insensitive. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2009/09/22/searching-and-navigating-code-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx for info

Comment: VS Search in Solution Explorer has the same problem- see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772811/searching-in-solution-explorer-should-have-case-insensitive-option and https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/7077558-solution-explorer-s-file-search-filter-is-case-sen